# Busqueda de cadena en un fichero tar.gz

Tags: linux

En un fichero comprimido tar.gz en la que hay multitud de ficheros, como puedo saber que fichero tiene una cadena de texto sin descomprimir el fichero tar.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes leer el contenido de los ficheros comprimidos en formato `tar.gz`. No creo que exista un sistema de compresión que mantenga el texto de los ficheros tras comprimirlo, porque no los estarían comprimiendo.

Lo que te recomiendo hacer es descomprimirlos dentro de una carpeta temporal del sistema, como `/tmp` en Linux o en la propia memoria del sistema.

Comment: `zgrep -a texto fichero.tar.gz` ?

Comment: Perfecto, pero ese programa lo descomprime en el directorio `/tmp` antes de realizar la comparación. Por lo que estás descomprimiendo, aunque no lo hagas explícitamente.

Comment: Perdona, pretendía poner el comentario en la pregunta, pero me equivoqué y lo puse en tu respuesta. En todo caso aprovecho para comentarte que obviamente para buscar un texto es necesario descomprimir el contenido, pero que eso no tiene por qué hacerse en disco, sino que puede hacerse en memoria (y de hecho eso es lo que hace `zgrep`, no usa la carpeta tmp). De hecho para buscar una línea en un fichero, basta ir procesando línea a línea lo que es muy eficiente en el uso de memoria.

Comment: Tienes razón, ojeando el código fuente, parece que lo hace en memoria. Edito la respuesta. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución que usa Python y su módulo `tarfile` para procesar el archivo completo en memoria, de forma eficiente (pues lee cada fichero línea a línea, en lugar de tratar de leerlo completo).

```
import tarfile
import sys

found = []

with tarfile.open(sys.argv[2], "r:gz") as t:
  for elem in t:
    if not elem.isfile():
       continue
    f = t.extractfile(elem)
    for n, linea in enumerate(f):
        if sys.argv[1].encode("utf-8") in linea:
           # print("{}:{} {}".format(elem.name, n, linea))
           found.append(elem.name)
           break

if not found:
    print("La cadena no aparece en ningún fichero")
    quit()

print("Cadena encontrada en los siguientes ficheros")
for filename in found:
    print(filename)
```

Guárdalo en un fichero llamado por ejemplo `buscar.py` y para ejecutarlo pones:

```
python3 buscar.py "texto a buscar" fichero.tar.gz
```

El resultado es simplemente una lista de qué ficheros dentro del tar.gz contienen la cadena en cuestión, por ejemplo podría mostrarte:

```
Cadena encontrada en los siguientes ficheros
./prueba.py
./data/app.R
./README.md
```

Se entiende que estos ficheros están dentro del `.tar.gz`

No obstante te indico que cuando luego pretendas extraer sólo esos, aún así `tar` tiene que procesar el fichero completo, por lo que tardará prácticamente lo mismo que si los extraes todos. Eso sí, ocuparás menos sitio en disco.